# Are there graphs for which A* cannot be admissible?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, a-star-search

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Properties) states that "On infinite graphs with a finite branching factor and edge costs that are bounded away from zero $ (d(x,y)>\varepsilon >0$ for some fixed $\varepsilon$), A* is guaranteed to terminate only if there exists a solution."

Does this mean that, if I have such a graph, then there is no admissible A* which exists for this graph? When one says that A* is not admissible, this means that its heuristic is not admissible, right?

Furthermore, is it correct to say that a heuristic is only admissible with respect to a graph - not generally admissible?

For example, if I have a infinite graph which has a finite branching factor, and the cost of each edge is 
half of the cost of the edge preceding it (something like this: $goal\leftarrow_{_{c=2}} start \rightarrow_{_{c=1}}q1 \rightarrow_{_{c=1/2}} q_2 \rightarrow ...$), the heuristic and therefore the A* is necessarily inadmissible as there exists no fixed $\epsilon>0$ that is less than the cost of any edge?

To generalize, the $epsilon$ constraint is to make sure that there is no infinite path who's total cost converges, thereby assuring termination?

Any clarification is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heuristic function $h:V \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is *an input to the $A^*$ algorithm. If the function is *admissible* then $A^*$ algorithm gives you the solution; however as you have noted for infinite graphs the edge weights must have a positive lower bound.

The point of the heuristic function is to find the shortest path in the *least amount of time*, *i.e.* lower the computational complexity; *because you are making informed decisions based on a heuristic* (hence the name).

Recall the heuristic function is ***admissible*** if $h(v)$ is always less than (or equal to) the true path cost to the goal node.

There is always an admissable $h$ namely $h(v)= 0$ for all $v$. In this extreme case it becomes [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Practical_optimizations_and_infinite_graphs).

Returning to the example you gave if you plug in the input $A^*(G,h)$ where $G$ is a description of $G$ and $h = 0$ then $A^*$ won't halt (geometric series $r = 2 \implies \sum_i r^i = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} \leq 2$ for all finite partial sums). But lets see if we can bypass that; lets try: \begin{equation} h(v) = \begin{cases} 3 & \text{if } v = q_1 \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases} \end{equation} as you can see $h$ is admissible (because $d(q_1 , \text{goal}) = 3$ on the nose) and $A^*$ will pick "goal" as its first node (because its two choices are $f(q_1) = 4$ or $f(\text{goal}) = 2$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it's cleared everything up. Quick last question: does it make sense to ask that a BFS or a DFS algorithm is admissible. BFS algorithms return the optimal solution (I believe),  but it doesn't have a heuristic, right? But since it doesn't have a heuristic, would that be equivalent to having a heuristic $h(n) = 0 \forall n$ - which is an admissible heuristic? Thanks.

Comment: Yea, exactly; BFS doesn't have a heuristic. The point of the heuristic is that you have given/"taught" the computer some "extra knowledge." The computer can use this knowledge to make "more informed decisions." The better the heuristic the faster the computer finds the solution; in other words, $h$ reduces the computational complexity of the problem.